# Is there a way to syncronize the current view extent in QGIS with Google Earth?

Tags: qgis, google-earth

I already have the openlayers plugin but it's not working has I need it and I wanted to have the same view on both QGIS and Google Earth. Any ideas?

Update:

I'm using the openlayers plugin which enables me to add the google iamgery as a layer in the TOC. But it takes a long time to load and messes up the scale i'm working with. So i would like to have qgis with my layers, and simultaneously have google earth displaying the same extent view.

Comment: Wait, so what exactly are you doing, what do you need, and how is it not working?

Comment: I use quite a lot the Openlayers plugin especially at tarining courses and it's not slow "per se", it depends on your internet connection. About the scale: providers like Google/Yahoo/Bing do not provide their maps at every possibile scale, but only at certain pre-defined scales. If I'm not wrong the number of levels available is 19/20. When you zoom in/out with QGIS the program adjust the scale to match the closer level.

Comment: If VE maps are good for you, try this WMS server

http://geoposer.com:443/server/services/ve.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the Click-fu plugin from Barry Rowlingson's repository (3rd party)? This allows you to click a location in the QGIS map and load the corresponding location into various web mapping services in your browser. Not quite what you're asking as the two images aren't synchronised, but close.

Comment: not exactly what i wanted, but you're right, its very close. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I note that when you start the openlayers plugin to view GE imagery, it resets the crs to a custom value. Is there an issue here?

Probably you are better to cut the imagery out of GE and reload it as a georeferenced image, and display it as a static raster layer in QGIS.

There may be some copyright issues doing this.

Other people who use that other software do that, but I notice they have also been trying to install a plugin for that other software which costs money which does what QGIS has been able to do for some time.

Answer (score 0):

For QGIS 2.0  plugin  Send2GE http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/send2google_earth/